# surprising constructors for a class!

Tags: c++, constructor

What is the problem here in this code? 
It gives segmentation fault. I found value of size in vector (int *a) 
is no more 3. How is this?

```
 #include <iostream> 

 using namespace std; 

 class vector 
 { 
  int *v; 
  int size; 
     public: 
  vector(int m) 
  { 
   v = new int[size = m]; 
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
    v[i] = 0; 
  } 
  vector (int *a) 
  { 
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
    v[i] = a[i]; 
  } 
  int operator*(vector &y) 
  { 
   int sum = 0; 
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
    sum += this -> v[i] * y . v[i]; 
   return sum; 
  }    
 }; 


 int main() 
 { 
  int x[3] = {1,2,3}; 
  int y[3] = {4,5,6}; 
  vector v1(3); 
  vector v2(3); 
  v1 = x; 
  v2 = y; 
  int R = v1 * v2; 
  cout << "R = " << R; 
  return 0; 
 }
```

Sincerely,
Srinivas Nayak

Comment: I had also given upvotes for answers. I always reward people who answers.

Comment: `std::vector<int>` works, why using anything else for the same job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence the reason it generates a fault is in the line
v1=x;

As you have no assignment operator this in effect becomes:
v1=vector(x)
Which called your int * constructor. This constructor runs with size initialised to garbage which causes the seg fault as the loop progresses towards invalid memory.

Strategically the problem is you want create a new object for a int * but you don't know how big the array is that you are pointing at.

Your code looks like you want to assume that the array is the correct size for the currently defined vector in which case the operator you want to define this function in preference to the constructor: operator=(int *)

You generally seem a bit confused about which object is which for example
 sum += this -> v[i] * y . v[i]; 
would normally jusy be written as in this context
 sum += v[i] * y . v[i];

Comment: You seems to be correct. But how v1=x; becomes v1=vector(x);? Is there any rule in standard? If such a serous mistake is there in code, then compiler must catch it...am I wrong?

Comment: @svin The compiler needs to match the operator =; the first thing it looks for is:
Vector::operator=(int *) [which you don't have]
So it looks at the assignments available and finds
vector::operator=(vector&) [which is generated by the compile]
In order to make this operator work it needs a vector on the RHS and PRESTO it notices that you have defined vector(int*) so it can make vector from a int array - so it does.

This stuff is confusing until you really get it - looking up the rule of three (and especially the reasons why such guidelines exist) might help you some.

Answer (score 4):

Apart for the problem with the allocation in your constructor `vector (int *a)`, you also need an overloaded assignment operator:

```
    int operator=(int *a) {
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                    v[i] = a[i];
    }
```

Since the following two make use of it:

```
v1 = x; 
v2 = y;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not surprising at all.

Your first constructor seems ok, the second one does miss the allocation for v.

Edit: v1 = x and v2 = y  doesn't make sense without overloading operator=.

Comment: Imho, upvoting a accepted answer is not **required**. Sometimes the only answer that gives the correct solution but is poorly written or written with a disrespectful tone and it doesn't deserve an upvote. However I totally agree with the fact that at least accepting good answers is mandatory.

Comment: but for v1 = x, second constructor is being called; checked with gdb. I was also thinking about operator=, but now I am not getting what is happening here and why so!

Comment: @Srin operator= seems the thing you want as in my answer below. But in general perhaps you should rethink the whole strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is homework!
Otherwise you should be using std::Vector

Couple of problems:

- A constructor should initialize all members.

  - Neither constructor does this.
- The copy constructor (or what seems to be) is not defined incorrectly.
- Because your class manages a RAW pointer you need to see "The rule of three"

  - ie you are missing the assignment operator
- Prefer to use initializer lists when you can

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the correct answers here, consider adding keyword *explicit* before all your constructors that accept only one argument. That way it will never be confused with assignment operations. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) another question that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  vector (int *a) 
  { 
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
    v[i] = a[i]; 
  }
```

This constructor couldn't possibly work.

- The `v` member is not initialized. You have not allocated storage for the values.
- The `size` member is uninitialized. The loop will try to read an undeterminate amount of values from the passed pointer.
- There is **no way to initialize** `size`. If you are given just an `int*`, there is no way to determine how large the pointed array is (if the pointer even points into an array in the first place). This is the reason, why the number of elements in the array has to be passed separately (and why plain arrays are a PITA).